# Plotting points on map returns "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, r-leaflet

I am new to Shiny. I have the following `test` data I want to plot:

```
      name     lat      long
1     AN-02M25 51.95509 -0.960327
2     AN-03M02 52.01291 -0.925606
3     AN-04M04 52.13251 -0.957313
4    AN-05268A 52.10275 -0.812983
5     AN-05M02 52.07297 -0.807966
```

My code is the following:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("recalc", "New points"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Order Locations", leafletOutput("map",width="80%",height="400px")),
      tabPanel("Markers", verbatimTextOutput("markers"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  points <- reactive({data=test})
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(lng=points$long,lat=points$lat)
  })
  output$markers <- renderPrint({print(points)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run this in RStudio, I get:

```
Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  [No stack trace available]
```

Am I passing `test` to `server` using the wrong reactive function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`points` is a [`reactive`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html). To access it, you need to use function call syntax (because it *is* essentially a function):

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(lng = points()$long, lat = points()$lat)
})
output$markers <- renderPrint({print(points())})
```

Also, the initialisation of your reactive is weird: you’re creating a second local object, `data`. That probably wasn’t intended. Replace `{data=test}` with just `test`:

```
points <- reactive(test)
```

Comment: Thanks. The error message is a bit cryptic though.

Comment: @Zizzipupp It is indeed (famously so, it is a meme at this point). But now that you’ve encountered it, you can recognise it more generally: this message virtually always means that you’ve either forgotten `()` after a function call/reactive value, or that you’re accessing a function instead of a variable (due to a typo, or because you’ve forgotten to initialise the variable in the current scope).